# How to make Firefox remember a self signed certificate is trusted

Tags: firefox, ssl, certificate

I'm using some private server with a self-signed certificate for https connections.

Firefox 25.0 warns me about the certificate being untrusted every time.

For some reason, I can't make it remember my choice and I have to confirm it every time :(

Which is risky, because after doing this a few hundred times, I'm now doing this semi-automatically without inspecting the actual details. So in case there actually *is* an eavesdropper or otherwise malicious certificate involved, I will probably accept it blindly :(

Is there a way around this??

Screenshot of what I mean.

[image]

Comment: This looks like [Remember Certificate Exception](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/remember-certificate-except/?src=search). Are you using the most up to date version?

Comment: Have you tried getting the certificate and importing it? If that doesn't work, what error do you get?

Comment: @Doktoro Reichard I'm using the latest Firefox version (currently version 25). Do you mean I need to install some add-on for this? If that works, it's ok with me, but.. seriously?

Comment: @mpez0 When I click "Get Certificate", I'm getting the error as displayed above in the screenshot ("Unknown Identity" etc). How do you mean "importing" it? What/where? (isn't that what I'm trying to do here, but Firefox won't let me?)

Comment: @Sheldon I never saw your screen in Firefox, rather there is an addon that enables you to override default SSL configuration that resembles that screen, hence the link and suggestion.

Comment: It looks like there are two different errors, one related to the CA certificate, and the second related to the signature. The signature could be the reason why permanent exception is disabled.

Answer (score 0):

This is answered in the Mozilla Support Forum: [SSL certificate exception impossible to add any more](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1131961).

When Firefox is not running, delete the file `SiteSecurityServiceState.txt` from your Firefox profile folder.

If you need to find your profile folder, type `about:support` in the URL bar.  This troubleshooting page actually has a button to open the folder in Windows Explorer for you, as well as displaying it so that you can select and copy the profile path.